# csvToArray and insert into database not working as intended

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Earlier in the week I was asking the community how I can insert the information from a function called csvToArray written by Ben Nadel, however, I ended up utilizing something else which seems to run just as good and or better.  So here is the problem now:  After using this new function I am able to grab the data from the array, however when I insert it into the Database I get the following error message from coldfusion :"*The element at position 16, of dimension 2, of an array object used as part of an expression, cannot be found.*"  Does anyone have any experience with this and know why I am receiving this message?  Everything else works as intended.  Here is the code in question:

```
    <cfif request_method is "Post" AND isDefined("form.fileUpload") EQ 1>
        <cffile action="read" file="#form.filecontent#" variable="csvfile">
            <cfinvoke component="#application.path.cfc#.Organizations" method="csvToArray" returnvariable="getArraData">
                <cfinvokeargument name="fileContent" value="#csvfile#">
            </cfinvoke>
    <!--- Loop the array starting on the 2 index to remove the header info from the insert --->
    <cfloop from="2" to="#arrayLen(getArraData)#" index="i">
    <cfset indexNum = i > <!--- Start with 2 index then increment the value by 1 on the loop --->
        <cfloop from="2" to="#arrayLen(getArraData[i])#" index="j">
            <cfset dimNum = j > <!--- Start with 2 index then increment the value by 1 on the loop --->
            <!--- After loop ends. nunbers are dynamically placed into position [2][2] and insert the values of the index  deminsion--->
                <cfquery datasource ="#application.dsn.name#" name="BudgetInsert">
                    <!--- Insert Data here --->
                        INSERT INTO sales_budget
                               (
                                nOrganizationID
                               ,nLocationID
                               ,nBudgetTypeID
                               ,nBudgetYear
                               ,month1
                               ,month2
                               ,month3
                               ,month4
                               ,month5
                               ,month6
                               ,month7
                               ,month8
                               ,month9
                               ,month10
                               ,month11
                               ,month12
                               ,nActive
                               ,tCreationDate
                               ,tLastUpdate
                               ,cChangedBy
                            )
                         VALUES
                               (
                                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.OrgID#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="2">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#getArraData[indexNum][dimNum]#">
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="1">
                               ,GetDate()
                               ,GetDate()
                               ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Session.Auth.UserID#">
                            )
                    </cfquery>
<cfset dimNum = j +1 >
            </cfloop>
indexNum = i +1
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
```

Comment: I figgured it out as the following:  The inner loop needed to have a reference to the outter loop as noted below:<cfloop from="2" to="#arrayLen(getArraData[i])#" index="j">

Comment: If you think the solution would help others, you should post it as an "answer". Answering your own question is allowed on S.O. That said, is there a reason you must use arrays as opposed to using DB tools to load the CSV , ie `BULK INSERT` (SQL Server), `LOAD DATA INFILE` (MySQL), etcetera.  Those are usually far more efficient than looping.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `cfspreadsheet` to read the CSV file and move it into the DB. While there are commands for most modern databases to directly import a CSV file (per Leigh's comment), if you don't have the correct permissions, then this is your best bet.

```
<cfspreadsheet  
    action="read"
    src = "filepath"
    columns = "range"
    columnnames = "comma-delimited list"
    excludeHeaderRow = "true | false"
    format = "CSV|HTML"
    headerrow = "row number"
    name = "text"
    query = "query name"
    rows = "range"
    sheet = "number"
    sheetname = "text">
```

This returns a normal CF query object which you can loop over for your inserts.